# how load Module rewrite without accessing to httpd.conf

Tags: cakephp, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

i am using cakephp and i need load Module rewrite , but i can not accessing to httpd.conf.
there is way to solve this problem ?
by thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a possibility if you do not have access to `conf` files.

Modules have to be loaded when Apache start. Nothing cam be done WRT this after Apache has started.

`mod_so` is used to load modules. Although DSO(Dynamic Shared Object) is used, a restart to the server is required.

from [Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/dso.html):

> The DSO support for loading individual Apache modules is based on a module named mod_so which must be statically compiled into the Apache core. It is the only module besides core which cannot be put into a DSO itself. Practically all other distributed Apache modules can then be placed into a DSO by individually enabling the DSO build for them via configure's --enable-module=shared option as discussed in the install documentation. After a module is compiled into a DSO named mod_foo.so **you can use mod_so's LoadModule command in your httpd.conf file to load this module at server startup or restart**.

Answer (score 0):

If your host has enabled it, you can place an `.htaccess` file in your CakePHP directory. Its contents must be the same as the ones you would want to write into the httpd.conf file. An example might be:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # Add your rewrite rules here
  RewriteRule ^/somepage$ somepage.php
</IfModule>
```